Jetpack Compose Navigation by keeping TopBar and NavBar fixed
I have seperate function for TopAppBar and Naigation_bar in jetpack compose how to fix these at their position and on click of Navigation_Bar item the navigation should happen that will change the main contents of the screen keeping TopAppBar and Naigation_bar fix at their position.
Currently OnClick I'm navigating to new screen every time but now I want that the screen should be same but only the content will change based on clicks.
Scaffold(
topBar = { TopBar() },
content = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.White)
            ) {
                NavigationBar(
                    modifier = Modifier

                        .weight(.2f),
                    navController = navController
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Drawer(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(.2f)
                    navController = navController,
                )

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(.6f)

                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        
                        ContentScreen(modifier = Modifier)

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    ) I'm using this for every screens but now I want that the screen should be same but only the content will change based on clicks.


A single componant should handle all of your componants.
Use a NavHost to control the navigation
basic example
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopBar() },
        bottomBar = { NavigationBar(navController = navController) }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "home",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            composable("home") { HomeContent() }
            composable("Page one") { ProfileContent() }
            composable("Page Two") { SettingsContent() }
            // more
        }
    }
}


import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
val navController = rememberNavController()

Scaffold(
    topBar = { TopBar() },
    bottomBar = {
        NavigationBar(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            navController = navController
        )
    },
    content = { paddingValues ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.White)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues) // Apply padding values from Scaffold
        ) {
            Drawer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.2f),
                navController = navController
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))

            // Main content area where content will change
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.8f)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = "home"
                ) {
                    composable("home") { HomeScreen() }
                    composable("profile") { ProfileScreen() }
                    composable("settings") { SettingsScreen() }
                    // Add other destinations here
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
}

@Composable
fun TopBar() {
TopAppBar(title = { Text("My App") })
}

@Composable
fun NavigationBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, navController: 
NavController) {
BottomNavigation(modifier = modifier) {
    BottomNavigationItem(
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Home, contentDescription = "Home") },
        label = { Text("Home") },
        selected = false,
        onClick = { navController.navigate("home") }
    )
    BottomNavigationItem(
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Person, contentDescription = 
"Profile") },
        label = { Text("Profile") },
        selected = false,
        onClick = { navController.navigate("profile") }
    )
    BottomNavigationItem(
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Settings, contentDescription = 
"Settings") },
        label = { Text("Settings") },
        selected = false,
        onClick = { navController.navigate("settings") }
    )
}
}

@Composable
fun Drawer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, navController: NavController) {
// Your drawer content here
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
Text("Home Screen", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
}

@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
Text("Profile Screen", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
}

@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
Text("Settings Screen", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
}

